# Django & Pandas: Get Choice Value in dataframe instead of Choice label

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-pandas

Again with a question regarding django... and pandas.

I'm trying to get the value of two 'choices' column into a pandas dataframe; however, I'm only getting the label of the choice.

Example code:

#### my_app/models.py

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    STATUS_ONE = 1
    STATUS_TWO = 2

    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (STATUS_ONE, 'Status one'),
        (STATUS_TWO, 'Status two')
    )

    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=STATUS_ONE)
    status_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    contents = models.TextField()
```

The data I'm getting:

```
from django_pandas import read_frame
from my_app.models import Entry
qs = Entry.objects.all()
df = read_frame(qs)
df
#      status                 status_date        contents
#  Status one   2018-04-30 20:00:00+00:00   Test contents
#  Status two   2018-04-30 21:00:00+00:00   More contents
```

What I'd like to get is:

```
#      status                 status_date        contents
#           1   2018-04-30 20:00:00+00:00   Test contents
#           2   2018-04-30 21:00:00+00:00   More contents
```

Is there a way to get it?

Comment: Now you need to use `from django_pandas.io import read_frame` instead of `from django_pandas import read_frame`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got it!

I simply need to add the **`verbose=False`** option to `read_frame`, and that's it:

```
df = read_frame(qs, verbose=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you are  getting this because of your `STATUS_CHOICES`.  The following:

```
def Entry(models.Model):
    STATUS_ONE = 1
    STATUS_TWO = 2

    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (STATUS_ONE, '1'),
        (STATUS_TWO, '2')
    )
```

Alternatively, have you tried doing it as a class instead of a function? e.g.,

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    STATUS_ONE = 1
    STATUS_TWO = 2

    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (STATUS_ONE, 'Status one'),
        (STATUS_TWO, 'Status two')
    )
```